# How to update Keras with conda

Tags: keras, conda

I'd like to update Keras to version 2.3.0 with conda.
Currently, I've got Keras 2.2.4 running.

First, I tried

```
conda update keras
```

which didn't work.
Then I tried

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken keras
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 keras
```

as suggested by https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras. This also didn't update Keras.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `keras` is collected in both the official channel and the conda-forge channel. Both of the two packages on Anaconda Cloud are not built the keras team, which explains why the package is outdated.
2. For the time being, 20191007, package `keras` 2.3.0 is available in the **conda-forge** channel, for Linux only.

[image]

Solution:

To get the `keras` 2.3.0 installed, make sure

1. install `keras` from `conda-forge` channel
2. you're installing it on Linux, otherwise the latest version you can get is 2.2.5

   ```sh
   conda upgrade -c conda-forge keras
   ```

---

If a "module is not found" error is thrown out, reinstall `keras` with `--strict-channel-priority` to make sure dependencies of `keras` are install from conda-forge as well.

```sh
conda install -c keras --strict-channel-priority
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pip uninstall keras
```

then

```
pip install keras
```

Answer (score 2):

Using conda in the command line, the command below would install keras 2.3.0.

```
conda install keras==2.3.0
```

Comment: need `conda config --add channels conda-forge` first